# Why does Xcode 4 include iostream in every header?

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4

I noticed that newly created CPP files in Xcode ~4 all `#include <iostream>`. I never use any iostream functionality, so usually strip them out (hearing they can gradually slow build times from the Google blink team blog). Are there any useful generic functions of iostream that make including it all the time valuable? Such as instrumentation or reflection features that not having it everywhere would break?

It seems like a bold step to add everywhere - especially given how conservative many groups software engineering! -  so feel there must be something important I'm missing.

Does anyone know the reason why this header has become so important it must be everywhere?

Comment: I can't imagine any good reason to always include *any* header, unless you always write code that uses it.

Comment: @juanchopanza It depends somewhat on the type of code you're writing.  I'd guess that something over 90% of our modules use `std::vector`.  In other applications I've worked on, however, it rarely appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I sign juanchopanzas statement: There is no header that needs to be included everywhere. Each `#include` should only be in a file when it is really needed.